# Dada una condición no ejecutar el resto del procedimiento almacenado en SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

Estoy automatizando la ejecución de un conjunto de consultas SELECT y UPDATE en un procedimiento almacenado. Para ello debo saber si una consulta SELECT NO cumple con las condiciones, y en ese caso, NO ejecutar del resto del procedimiento.

Una opción es utilizar WHILE y BREAK, pero quizás existe algo mejor:

```
DECLARE @ESTADO AS BIT, @condicion_1 AS BIT, @condicion_2 AS BIT

SET @ESTADO = 1

WHILE @ESTADO = 1
BEGIN
     /* Prueba N°1. */
    SET @condicion_1 = 0 -- Condición que NO se cumple.
    -- SET @condicion_1 = 0 -- Condición que se cumple.

    IF (@condicion_1 = 1)
    BEGIN
        PRINT 'Prueba N°1: OK.'
        BREAK; -- Sale del presente WHILE y ejecuta el resto del procedimiento.
    END

    ELSE
    BEGIN
        PRINT 'Prueba N°1: STOP.'
        SET @ESTADO = 0 -- Sale del presente WHILE y NO ejecuta el resto del procedimiento.
    END
END

WHILE @ESTADO = 1
BEGIN
     /* Prueba N°2. */
    -- SET @condicion_2 = 0 -- Condición que NO se cumple.
    SET @condicion_2 = 1 -- Condición que se cumple.

IF (@condicion_2 = 1)
    BEGIN
        PRINT 'Prueba N°2: OK.'
        BREAK; -- Sale del presente WHILE y ejecuta el resto del procedimiento.
    END

    ELSE
    BEGIN
        PRINT 'Prueba N°2: STOP.'
        SET @ESTADO = 0 -- Sale del presente WHILE y NO ejecuta el resto del procedimiento.
    END
END
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para terminar la ejecución de un procedimiento almacenado (o función) puedes añadir la instrucción `RETURN`. En general, se usa el 0 para indicar que el procedimiento se completó satisfactoriamente, y se usan otros valores para indicar errores o situaciones fuera de lo normal.

Más información en [la documentación de Microsoft](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/sql/t-sql/language-elements/return-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)